# HTML --- Javascript/JSON

Tags: javascript, json

okay here is the question -- .. i tried it but my js isn't working and idk where i am wrong [here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSG8g.png)

THE PROBLEM IS AFTER THE JS EXECUTED IT DOESN'T RUN ... LIKE IDK WHERE THE PROBLEM IS ; I KNOW IT LOADS BUT IT DOES'NT WORK

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="q2.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
 </head>
 <div > Input 1 <input type="text" id ="input1"></div>
  <div> Input 2 <input type="text" id ="input2"> </div>
  <div> Result <div id="result"> </div></div>
  <button onclick= "compute()">Compute</button>

 </body>
 </html>
```

the js is here

```
 function compute(){
 var n = (document.getElementById("input1").value;
 var m = document.getElementById("input2").value;

 var i,j;

if (Number(n)){
}
 else {
   alert("Error! Please put a valid Number - on input 1 ");
   }
  if (Number(m)){
   }
   else {
    alert("Error! Please put a valid Number - on input 2 ");
   }

       for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
          result.innerHTML += "X";
          if(j == (m-1)){
          result.innerHTML += "<br />";
          }
      }
     }
  }
```

Comment: `here is the question` a link to an external image is useless for future readers of this question if that image goes away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.innerHTML += "X";`

You forgot to set the variable `result`:
`var result = document.getElementById("result");`

And there is a loneley `(` in `var n = (document.getElementById("input1").value;` wich will through syntax error

And you might want to clear the content of your "result"-container when calling the function again: `result.innerHMLT = ''`

```js
function compute() {
  var n = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var m = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  
  result.innerHMLT = ''

  var i, j;

  if (Number(n)) {} else {
    alert("Error! Please put a valid Number - on input 1 ");
  }
  if (Number(m)) {} else {
    alert("Error! Please put a valid Number - on input 2 ");
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      result.innerHTML += "X";
      if (j == (m - 1)) {
        result.innerHTML += "<br />";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Input 1
  <input type="text" id="input1">
</div>
<div>Input 2
  <input type="text" id="input2">
</div>
<div>Result
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="compute()">Compute</button>
```